# Como mudar a cor do texto digitado no input?

Tags: html, css

Tenho um `input` e quando digito algo nele o texto fica com a **mesma** *cor do fundo*(branca).

Alguém sabe como faço para editar isso? Gostaria de colocar a **cor** do *texto* **preto**.

Comment: dê uma olhada [neste curso](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/make-a-website), com certeza vai te ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta colocar o atributo `color` como `black`, segue dois exemplos de como alterar a cor do `input`,

Exemplo: texto com cor preta

```css
input{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Exemplo: texto com cor vermelha

```css
input{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar o color no CSS:

```html
<input type="text" style="color: black;">
```

Answer (score 2):

É simples, é só colocar o atributo CSS `color` do input com a cor que você quiser. Para os inputs do tipo caixa de texto, a propriedade `color` se refere à cor do texto.

Algo como:

```
input { color: white }
```

Ou

```
input { color: #ffffff } /* forma pedante */
```

Com jQuery:

```
$("input").css("color", "white");
```

Você também pode usar seletores mais específicos, como por exemplo uma classe, ou o identificador do seu *input*.